# Typescript Angular Cannot find name

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am working on Aspnet Core Angular project and getting following error:

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'email'.

The code is executed in visual studio 2017.

```js
postEmailValidate(email?: string): Observable<any> {
    var data: {
        "Email": email,
        "Timeout": "5",
        "Verbose": "True"
    };        
    return this.http.post(
        this.urlEmailValidate,
        data,
        { headers: this.getHeaders("POST") }
        )
        //.delay(5000)
        .map(this.handleSuccess)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

The code is very basic and I have declared a variable in the function's call. But the compiler gives the following error. Am I forgetting something or is it a visual studio issue?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a wrong syntax for object delcaration. Replace `var data:` with `var data =`

```
var data = {
    "Email": email,
    "Timeout": "5",
    "Verbose": "True"
};
```

Comment: My bad :P.
Thanks alot for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign values to data:

```
var data = {
    "Email": email,
    "Timeout": "5",
    "Verbose": "True"
};
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer